# Angular 6: Routing from sibling to sibling's child

Tags: angular, routes, nested, angular-material, parent-child

This is the structure of my project:

[image]

**This is the routing table:**

```js
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/courses', pathMatch: 'full', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' },
  { path: 'courses', component: CourseListComponent,  pathMatch: 'full', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' },
  { path: 'courses/:id', component: CourseDetailComponent, pathMatch: 'full', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' },
  { path: 'courses/:id/unit/:unit', component: CoursePlayComponent, pathMatch: 'full', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    children: [
      { path: 'lesson/:id', component: CourseLessonComponent},
      { path: 'quiz/:id', component: CourseQuizComponent }
  ]},
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent, pathMatch: 'full', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' }];
```

**This are my interfaces:**

```js
export interface ICourse {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  author: string;
  course_details: string;
  units: IUnit[];
}

export interface IUnit {
  id: number;
  course_id: number;
  position: number;
  name: string;
  videos: IVideo[];
  quiz: IQuiz;
}

export interface IVideo {
  id: number;
  unit_id: number;
  unit_position: number;
  position: number;
  name: string;
  data: string;
}

export interface IQuiz {
  id: number;
  unit_id: number;
  unit_position: number;
  name: string;
  questions: IQuestion[];
}
```

In Course-play I use mat-sidebar, and the body contains the children lesson or quiz.
I want that when I click on lesson in Course-detail, the route will change to the child and not stay as the parent, like that:

[image]

When I click from course-detail it's working but the route stay /courses/:id/unit/:unit_id and not changing to /courses/:id/unit/:unit_id/lesson/:lesson_id.

EDIT: I tried to write this in course-play component and I got Page not Found:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl(`/courses/${this.course.id}/unit/${unitPosition}/lesson/${lessonPosition}`);
```

This is the code:

**course-detail.html:**

```html
<!-- Body -->
      <div id="course_detail" class="row justify-content-lg-center">
        <ngb-tabset>

            <!-- Tab Content -->
              <ngb-tab title="Curiculum" id="Curiculum">
                <ng-template ngbTabContent>
                <h5>Course Overview</h5>
                <div *ngFor="let unit of course.units">
                  <h6>Unit {{ unit.position }}: {{ unit.name }}</h6>
                  <ul *ngFor="let lesson of unit.videos">
                    <a class="course_detail_item" [routerLink]="['unit', unit.position]"
                    (click)="setLessonPosition(lesson.position)"><li>Lesson {{lesson.id}}:
                     {{lesson.name}}</li></a>
                  </ul>
              </div>
            </ng-template>
            </ngb-tab>

              <ngb-tab title="About" id="About">
                <ng-template ngbTabContent>
                  <h5>About this course</h5>
                  <h6>Course Topics:</h6>
                  <p>{{course.course_details}}</p>   
                  <h6>Course Expectations:</h6>
                  <ul>
                    <li> Watch {{getLength(course)}} videos</li>
                  </ul>

                  <h6>Additional Resources:</h6>
                  <ul><li> see Labguru for more details </li></ul>
                </ng-template>
              </ngb-tab>
    </ngb-tabset>
  <div>

    <!-- Enable routing to course-play html page -->
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**course-play.html**

```html
<mat-sidenav-container fullscreen *ngIf="course">

  <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" class="app-sidenav">
    <mat-toolbar id="sidenav" color="primary">
      <span class="toolbar-filler">
          <h3 class="logo-title">{{course.title}}</h3>
      </span>
      <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()" class="mat-icon-button sidenav-
        toggle-button" [hidden]="!sidenav.opened">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Menu" class="material-icons">close</mat-icon>
      </button>
    </mat-toolbar>
      <mat-nav-list *ngFor="let unit of course.units">
        <h6 class="course-list-title">Unit {{ unit.position }}: {{ unit.name }}</h6>
        <a mat-list-item *ngFor="let lesson of unit.videos" class="sidenav-link course-item"
        [routerLink]="['/courses' , course.id , 'unit' , unit.position , 'lesson' ,
          lesson.position]" (click)="sidenav.toggle()"
          (click)="getCurrent(unit.position,lesson.position)">
          <span mat-line class="title">Lesson {{lesson.id}}: {{lesson.name}}</span>
        </a>
        <a mat-list-item *ngIf="unit.quiz" class="sidenav-link course-item" [routerLink]="
          ['/courses' , course.id , 'unit' , unit.position , 'quiz' , unit.quiz.id]" 
          (click)="getQuiz(unit.position)" (click)="sidenav.toggle()"
          (click)="getQuiz(unit.position)">
          <span mat-line class="title">Quiz</span>
        </a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-toolbar id="appToolbar" color="white">
    <button mat-icon-button (click)="sidenav.toggle()" class="mat-icon-button sidenav-toggle-button" [hidden]="sidenav.opened">
        <mat-icon aria-label="Menu" class="material-icons">menu</mat-icon>
    </button>
  </mat-toolbar>

    <div class="course-body container-fluid text-center">
      <course-lesson *ngIf="showLesson === true" [lesson]="current" [totalLesoons]="totalLesoons"></course-lesson>
      <quiz-course *ngIf="showQuiz === true" [questions]="currentUnitQuiz?.questions" [quizName]="currentUnitQuiz?.name"></quiz-course>

    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </div>
    
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**NOTE:** I added only the html files because the functions in the ts files suppose to work. The main problem is with routing, I want the current route of course-play will change if I activate the child and I want from the start when in course-detail it'll do it.

Comment: I suppose you want to use named outlets to display different components alongside -> https://angular.io/guide/router#displaying-multiple-routes-in-named-outlets

Comment: I want that the route of the parent change and that the component stay the same if I made myself clear. maybe I need to use CanActivate but I'm not sure because I'm new to routing in this depth

Answer (score 0):

If you can provide a stackblitz link it will be easier to debug, but you can try adding the code shown below and see if it works.

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [{ path: '', redirectTo: '/courses', pathMatch: 'full', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' },
{ path: 'courses', component: CourseListComponent,  pathMatch: 'full', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' },
{ path: 'courses/:id', component: CourseDetailComponent, pathMatch: 'full', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' },
{ path: 'courses/:id/unit/:unit', component: CoursePlayComponent, pathMatch: 'full', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always',
    children: [
    Add one liner code below and see if it works.
    { path: '', redirectTo: lesson/:id, pathMatch:'full'} 
    { path: 'lesson/:id', component: CourseLessonComponent},
    { path: 'quiz/:id', component: CourseQuizComponent }]},
{ path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent, pathMatch: 'full', runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always' }];
```

Comment: I tried upload to stackblitz but I couldnt drag the folder there and I can't copy paste that many files.

Comment: I tried to do what you said but It said cannot find 'id'

Comment: after I remove the pathMatch full, it worked but everytime I clicked on other lesson in the sidebar it upload below the already open lesson and didn't refresh the div. also the quiz appeared below the lesson and not reload the div. Also when I tried to enter the route /courses/3/unit/1/lesson/1 the page was white, and not "Page Not Found" as last time, and when I inspect the page it seems it's upload course play and course lesson but nothing was showing

Comment: ok it's worked and I did repo in stackblitz. it's not working because I'm using sass files. this is the repo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zkn6zd but I can't save